# Need help editing a question to bring it into clearer focus

Tags: support

There is a [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83700/32436) about perceptions of students with disabilities using the "reasonable accommodation" of extra time for tests.  That's an interesting question, and sent me hunting for research about perceptions.  I found some articles.

But the question asks other things too.  Maybe it's asking for tactical advice based on people's perceptions.  But it's hard to be sure if that's what the OP meant.

I have not voted to reopen the question because I think it needs to be edited first.  But I can't figure out how to do that.

Based on answers and comments received so far, this question looks like it may generate polemics, misunderstandings, things said that people might (or should) regret later, bitter reactions....

I suppose the easy way out would be to edit the question to focus on a reference request, to find out what has been found in studies regarding professors' perceptions of accommodations.

Another way to narrow the focus would be to ask what is permitted and not permitted in the U.S.: is it a violation of 504, ADA and/or FERPA for a reference to (a) flag the student as having used an extra time accommodation, or (b) use the fact of the extra time to un-level the playing field after the fact?

I just wish I knew what motivated the question for the OP.  Is it that s/he is trying to decide whether to ask for or utilize accommodations?

They are all interesting questions, but I think that as currently written, the questions is just going to generate nonconstructive debate.  I don't enjoy watching respected colleagues here on Academia SE say bigoted, embarrassing things.

So... can someone please help edit the question so that it will not lead to a lot of acrimony?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems quite clear to me; it is explicitly asking about perceptions. We have other questions on this site asking about how "X" is perceived. Some examples can be found [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+is+perceived+is%3Aquestion).

I do not think it is appropriate to turn it into a question about the law, as that seems inconsistent with the OP's intent. (Not to mention, we don't even know what country the OP is in.)

> Based on answers and comments received so far,

We have systems for dealing with bad content. If you see comments that are not constructive, flag them using the "not constructive" comment flag. If you see a problem with something written in an answer, leave a comment on the answer explaining what the problem is. (And downvote if you feel the answer is unhelpful.) Help good answers rise to the top by voting them up, and write your own answer if necessary.

Comment: OP also asked, "If a student is looking forward to requesting a reference for grad school from a certain professor, would it generally be better for him/her not to request exam extensions for this professor's course?"  // I'm not sure how to completely set aside the legal aspect of the question, since it could be considered discriminatory (by OCR) to take disability accommodations into account when writing an LOR.

Comment: @aparente001 If you feel that a legal answer addresses the question, by all means write a legal answer. You don't have to change the question to do that. Other answers can address the perception question (main question) and/or that "If a student is looking forward" question as they prefer.

Comment: @aparente001 P.S. as far as I can tell, the OP on that question has not specified any country.

Comment: You're right, but from the way the question was worded, it felt like a U.S.-based question. // "How do professors perceive extra time?" feels like a poll, and an invitation for lots of subjective posts like Pete's for example.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't find it different from our other [How is X perceived?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+is+perceived+is%3Aquestion) questions. Most of those seem to do OK.